# I want to get the location of the dropped file in pyqt5 window and save it to a variable to use it in an another pyhton file but it doesnt work

Tags: python, pyqt

---

This code does print the location of the dropped file but I can not get that information and save it to a global variable. I tried converting files into str and list but none worked.

---

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QMimeData
import sys
global URL

URL =str()

class MainWidget(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Sürükle Bırak")
        self.resize(720, 480)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        files = [u.toLocalFile() for u in event.mimeData().urls()]
        print(files)
        URL=str(files)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = MainWidget()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: When assigning to a variable anywhere in a function, the variable is seen as local and shadows other variables if not declared as "global" explicitly.

Comment: Don't use global variables. Use an attribute: `self.files = files`. (And don't do `str(files)` as this won't give you want you want).